# iterate over all columns of a pandas dataframe and count the values in each column (pd.Series.value_counts(dropna=False)) not working

Tags: python, dataframe

I'd like to iterate over all colums of my pandas dataframe and count the values in each column.

So I've executed the following code `df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)` which worked well for me.

However, now I'd like to add the argument 'dropna=False' to my code like the following: `df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts(dropna=False))`. But now I am getting the following error:

```
value_counts() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Do someone know, how to resolve this issue?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lambda in order to pass the argument `dropna=False` into `value_counts` function

```
df.apply((lambda x: pd.Series.value_counts(x, dropna=False)))
```

Let me know if it gave the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the suggested code will result in the exact same behaviour as if, I remove the argument (dropna=False). Seems that the argument is not forwarded to the function.

Comment: @blackrafi It seems to be working on my sample data. Could you upload the sample data you're using and the expected output?

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion works perfectly. There was a little error on my script. Thank you!